# Error when trying to update an account on Solana built with anchor

Tags: anchor, account

Here's the error I am getting:
[image]

Link to transaction: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5LSyn7NfjK4me56nU8fiYVb9RGXCe7AJ7MBFYKBfcvxh35sLN9krkYU7fFLTJWWW6iz3aTpu3K4kXdhwAb8kydEq?cluster=devnet

Here's the code to update the account:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

use crate::config::Config;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateConfig<'info> {
    #[account(constraint = admin.key() == config.admin)]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub config: Account<'info, Config>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn handler(
    ctx: Context<UpdateConfig>,
    reward_mint: Pubkey,
    reward_token: Pubkey,
    rewards_per_day: u64,
    min_staking_period: u8,
) -> Result<()> {
    let config = &mut ctx.accounts.config;

    config.reward_mint = reward_mint;
    config.reward_token = reward_token;
    config.rewards_per_day = rewards_per_day;
    config.min_staking_period = min_staking_period;

    Ok(())
}
```